# Is this proof of a version of Lyapunov stability correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, stability-in-odes

In a textbook I have seen a stability result known as Dirichlet's theorem: let $$\dot{x} = f(x)$$ be  $C^{r}$  a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $r \geq 1$, with a fixed point at $x = \bar{x}$. Let $I(x)$ be first integral of the vector field defined in a neighbourhood of $x = \bar{x}$ such that $x = \bar{x}$ is a nondegenerate minimum of $I(x)$. Then $x = \bar{x}$ is Lyapunov stable.

My proof: since $I(x)$ is the first integral, then $\dot{I}(x) = 0$. Since $\bar{x}$ is the nondegenerate minimum of $I(x)$, we have $I(x) > I(\bar{x})$ for all $x \neq \bar{x}$, in a neighbourhood of $\bar{x}$. Define $\tilde{I}(x) = I(x) - I(\bar{x})$. Then $\tilde{I}(\bar{x}) = 0$ and $\tilde{I}(x) >0$ for $x \neq \bar{x}$, in an neighbourhood of $\bar{x}$. Since $\dot{\tilde{I}} = \dot{I}=0$, we may define $\tilde{I}$ to be the Lyapunov function and by the above criteria $\bar{x}$ is indeed stable.

Is this correct?

Comment: All is correct. In case when you have first integral you can prove Lyapunov stability even not using Lyapunov's second method (by constructing $\varepsilon$- and $\delta$-neighbourhoods). Additional question: can this equilibrium be asymptotically Lyapunov stable?)

Comment: Thanks, Evgeny. Regarding asymptotic stability, I think it cannot, due to the nondegeneracy of the minimum of $I$, but I don't know how to prove or disprove my intuition. How would you approach this? @Evgeny

Comment: There are two ways how to explain this. First one uses nondegeneracy of the minimum: the local structure of level set follows from [Morse lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse_lemma). The second one uses the fact that function is locally non-constant. Suppose this equilibrium were Lyapunov asymptotically stable. Then it had at least small neighbourhood of points that go to this equilibrium. What value of first integral do they have then?

Comment: Ah, I see. Indeed, for those points that go to equilibrium, we would have $I$ take the minimum value, but this would contradict the nondegeneracy of the minimum. Hence there are no points in the neighbourhood of $\bar{x}$ that tend to it. @Evgeny

Comment: Yep, exactly :) I like the second method because it doesn't require knowing some fine structure of level sets and it just uses property that function is locally non-constant.

Comment: @Evgeny: It is always a pleasure to see read your comments. But could you elaborate why $\tilde{I}$ and $\dot{\tilde{I}}\equiv 0$ implies that the equilibrium point is a center and not an asymptotic equilibrium point? Intuitively it is clear but I would like to understand it in a more formal sense.

Comment: @MrYouMath Suppose that you have an asymptotically stable equilibrium $p$ and a first integral for which $p$ is a strict minimum. Because it is an asymptotically stable equilibrium, there is a neighbourhood $G$ of $p$ in which for all trajectories $\gamma(t)$ holds $\gamma(t) \rightarrow p$ when $t \rightarrow +\infty$. The first integral is differentiable and thus continuous, so $I(\gamma(t)) \rightarrow I(p)$. But at the same time $I(\gamma(t)) = I(\gamma(0))$ along trajectory. It means that for any point $x \in G$ holds $I(x) = I(p)$ — a contradiction with $p$ being a local minimum.

Comment: Thank you @Evgeny! I will have to think about this a little bit more until I fully internalize this reasoning.